# F# how to fill array with for loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, f#

How do you fill an array with a for loop? 
I'm trying to do this, but I need to fill my array at declaration. Or Am I just wrong?

I need to do this with a 2 dimensional array, it's not necessary, just 2 arrays is also fine

Comment: I think this will help you: https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/f12-arrays/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use a for loop. You can use `Array.init` or `Array.zeroCreate` if you want to fill it with the default value.

For 2d arrays the same functions are available in the module `Array2D`, here's an example:

```
let x: int [,] = Array2D.zeroCreate 2 6
```

It creates and initialise an array of 2x6 with `0`.

Filling your array at the declaration is actually a good practice, that's why this way is better than using for loops.

Comment: And how do I fill the array with user input?

Comment: @sofboy There is also an `Array2D.init` function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353720.aspx) which lets you fill the array based on a generator function.